# Consume click when dragging an annotation

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using `addOnMapLongClickListener` to create annotations on long clicks. Something like:

```java
mapboxMap.addOnMapLongClickListener(point -> {
  // create an annotation here
  return true;
});
```

Those annotations are created "draggable". Something like:

```java
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .withLatLng(latLng)
    .withCircleColor(ColorUtils.colorToRgbaString(Color.YELLOW))
    .withCircleRadius(12f)
    .withDraggable(true);

circleManager.create(circleOptions);
```

And I can drag the annotation without a problem. The thing is that it also triggers the long click listener, and therefore dragging an annotation results in the creation of a new one at the previous position.

How can I make it such that a drag does not trigger the long click listener on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized it is actually a [known issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/883).